# Is there any way to use same fingerprint authentication for android and iOS once it registered?

Tags: android, ios, native, biometrics

I want to use same fingerprint that user registered while signing up to app when he signed up than can I use that fingerprint for ios / android if user is registered to app form android / ios?

Comment: How you are planning to get fingerprint from user??

Comment: on iOS, fingerprints are registered on the device.  They are not linked to a specific person and the fingerprint data cannot be extracted from the Secure Enclave on the device.

Comment: when user will sign up I'll ask him/her to setup biometric login for the app and if he / she setup biometric for app then he/she can able to login via same biometric from android/ios as well

Comment: ANything like that is going to be tied to a single device.  You can't get the fingerprint from secure storage, and its unlikely it would work across scanners if you could.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In iOS finger print data is not transferable, i.e. there is no way to access it. You only request the iOS to authenticate and iOS does the authentication and gives success/failure to your app. I assume android does the same since finger print is user's sensitive data and exposing to mobile apps would be a blunder.

**Bonus Info:** Even apple don't have access to the biometric data of the user. It remains on the device not on their server. Once the device is cleaned data is gone.

Answer (score 1):

For android you can't save user finger-print in your app, you can only get already registered fingerprints from user device. So , what you're asking is not possible here.

Answer (score 1):

Nope. You can't use the same fingerprint and it's impossible to do that.